# Suggestions for calculus review for mGRE

Tags: reference-request, advice, gre-exam

I'm currently studying for the mGRE that will be given in October of this year and I'm having trouble deciding which books to use for the calculus review. I'm currently brushing up in Stewart's Precalculus and was planning on moving to Spivak after. I also have Apostol's Calculus, which seems to cover a lot of relevant material like DEs, vector calc, and some linear algebra, but I'm not sure which text to devote time to. Also, I've read the comments left by other users that seem to indicate that Stewart's Calculus is important for the mGRE-type problems. I would appreciate any suggestions so I can start to study more efficiently for the test. Thanks.

Comment: By mGRE, do you mean the math GRE subject test or the math portion of the general test?

Comment: @user211393 can you suggest reference which provides syllabus of exam you are to give(mGRE)

Comment: I mean the Math Subject Test.

Comment: You shouldn't just focus on Calculus then.

Comment: @dustin Right, I'm just referring to the calculus portion of the test here.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Thomas's Calculus as well as Hille's Calculus (as a secondary source).

Comment: Is there anything in particular that makes these books stand out as prep for the mGRE?

Comment: Thomas's book (in my opinion) gives a great balance between theory and applications. It contains many important techniques that are not usually found in an introductory calculus textbook (e.g. rationalizing substitutions in integration, big oh and little O methods, etc.). It's also very visual, but not lacking in rigor. Finally, it contains several GRE-type exercises that you practice with.

Comment: Hille's Calculus, although a more theoretical than Thomas's, also has GRE-type exercises for you to work on.